# "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String" when try to move file into another folder after upload files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing a complexity about file moving in Ruby on Rails.

I want to move the file to another folder after finished uploading, here is my code snippet

```
def create
    file = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/files/**/*.csv")
    file.each do |filesrc|
        # => get file name
        file_name =  File.basename(filesrc, ".csv")
        # => get use_id from file name
        user_id = file_name.scan(/\d+/).first
        # => send request for upload into model
        History.import(filesrc, user_id)

        #=> for moving this file
        dest = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/files_old/")
        FileUtils.mv(filesrc, dest)
    end
end
```

that is my code & it's working properly for importing to DB but after that not moving to `histories_old` and showing below error

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String

What I'm doing wrong with this code?

Really appreciate if solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `"#{Rails.root}/public/files_old/"` as a string in your destination, like this:

`FileUtils.mv(filesrc, "#{Rails.root}/public/files_old/")`

EDIT: As mentioned below in the comment by Johan, FileUtils.mv expects a string as its destination, but Dir.glob provides an array, which you are providing as destination to FileUtils.mv

Comment: Although this answer is correct you might want to add that [`FileUtils::mv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) expect a string as destination argument while an array (the result of [`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob)) is provided.